# Select a property in JavaScript called @something with Mustache.js?

Tags: mustache

I am consuming a JSON service via JavaScript that returns data with OData properties like @odata.count.

How can I access the property @odata.count with a Mustache template?

`{{@odata.count}}` and `{{odata.count}}` does not work.

In JavaScript I do this: `result["@odata.count"]` to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `@` that's killing you, it's the `.`… There's no way to access that property in Mustache, because `.` means the same thing in Mustache as it does in JavaScript. You'll need to prepare your data before rendering.